# JXA error with PDFDocument

Tags: objective-c, quartz-graphics, javascript-automation

I'm rewriting some python scripts into JXA, but having some difficulties. Here's the code:

```
ObjC.import('Quartz')
var pdfURL = $.NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filename)
var pdfDoc = $.PDFDocument.alloc.initWithURL(pdfURL)
var numberPages = pdfDoc.pageCount
```

This works, giving me the page count, but then it flags an error:

Error: exception raised by object: -[__NSArrayM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fafe7cbd610 (-2700)

The working python code is:

```
    import Quartz
    pdfURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath_(filename)
    pdfDoc = PDFDocument.alloc().initWithURL_(pdfURL)
    numberPages = pdfDoc.pageCount()
```

Comment: Seems to work here. Though with AppleScript technologies being quietly shuffled off to bit-rot in maintenance mode, JXA may not be a good long-term investment, even when it does work. If JavaScript is your thing, Node.js is well supported and has a Cocoa bridge, nodobjc, in npm. Or you could bite the bullet and use Swift, which you can run as 'scripts' by putting `#/usr/bin/env swift [-F FRAMEWORK …]` at the top of your text file and making it executable.

Comment: Yes, I've done some Swift scripts with decent success. I might just stick with that and python, as JXA seems to be bad. Good to know it works for you, though.